# Тост не отображается при переадресации

Tags: angular2, angular

Использую фреймворк **PRIMENG**.  Я хочу сделать так, чтобы, если пользователь случайно перешел на страницу которая требует авторизации, то его должно сразу перенести на страницу входа в систему и отобразить тост «Для начала авторизуйтесь в системе». Но по какой-то причине тост не отображается (Он не работает только в этом случае, у меня есть еще один тост если пользователь ввел не верный логин или пароль и он работает). Вот как выглядит url переадресации: `/login?accessDenied=tru`. Как это можно исправить?

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  providers: [MessageService]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      if (params['accessDenied']) {
        this.messageService.add({severity:'warn', summary: 'Предупреждение', detail:'Для начала авторизуйтесь в системе'});
      }
    })
  }

}
```

html:

```
<p-toast [ngStyle]="{marginTop: '80px'}"></p-toast>
```

Comment: вы уверены что получаете параметры? :)

Comment: @overthesanity Да. Я попробовал использовать тост из библиотеки `ngx-toastr` и все заработало, а вот у `primeng` не работает

Comment: оберните `this.messageService.add(...)` в `setTimeout` или перенесите код в `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: @overthesanity  Блин, добавил в `ngAfterViewInit` заработало, спасибо)

Comment: можно оформить ответом? :)

Comment: @overthesanity Конечно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам предлагаю 2 воркэраунда. Эта проблема, к сожалению, связана с костыльностью библиотеки `primeng`. Вы генерируете событие в `ngOnInit` родительского компонента, в то время как компонент `p-toast` еще не инициализирован.

По нормальному там должен использоваться генератор с кешированием - `BehaviorSubject` или `ReplaySubject`, но увы там используется обычный `Subject` и компонент `p-toast` не получает вашего сообщения при подписке.

Вы можете обернуть `this.messageService.add` в `setTimeout`, тогда событие сгенерируется асинхронно после того как Angular проведет все инициализации.

Второй вариант - это просто перенести ваш код с `ngOnInit` в `ngAfterViewInit`, после того как все дочерние компоненты будут проинициализированы.

И кстати - у вас утечка памяти:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(...);
```

Лучше всего получать параметры синхронно и вовсе не подписываться:

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const accessDenied = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('accessDenied');

  if (accessDenied) {
    this.messageService.add({ severity:'warn', summary: 'Предупреждение', detail:'Для начала авторизуйтесь в системе' });
  }
}
```

P.S. - я бы все таки обернул `this.messageService.add` в `setTimeout`, чтобы избежать `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, потому что мы фактически заставляем дочерний компонент перерендерится, на одном и том же механизме обнаружения изменений.